# Tableau Draw Financial Data Series

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to tableau. I am just trying the simplest task: I want to draw a stock price time trend. I have data and I have price. But no matter how I tried, tableau seems no option for this raw data drawing-- you have to select a measure, whether sum or average or count but no option for just raw data. Can someone tell me how to do this? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Sum should be fine and as you add dimensions the granularity will be determined. For example, Take one of your stocks and add the date to columns and the symbol to rows. Most likely you want to see daily close price so right click and change to exact date. At this point the sum shouldn't matter because you should only have one price for each day in your record. If you have hourly price data, I would suggest using close price or change the date to the hour level.

Answer (score 0):

In the Analysis menu uncheck aggregate measures, then no aggregations are performed on the measures and you see all the values.